# Django Rest framework with Many to Many framework with a intermediate model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Iam not sure how to serialize data for following models, for expected JSON file.

Here are my models:

```
class CheckModel(models.Model):
    check_name     =   models.CharField(max_length=1024,unique=True)
    RulesToWaivers =   models.ManyToManyField('RulesToWaivers',blank=True,default='default')

class RulesToWaivers(models.Model):
    rule    =   models.ManyToManyField('Rule',blank=True )
    waiver  =   models.ManyToManyField('Waiver',blank=True)
    deliverables     =  models.ManyToManyField('Deliverables',blank=True)


class Waiver(CommonInfo):
    desc =   models.TextField(blank=True)

class Rule(models.Model):
    rule_description =  models.CharField(max_length=512,blank=True) 

class Deliverables(CommonInfo):
    name        =   models.CharField(max_length=1024,blank=True)
```

And following are my serializers

```
class CheckModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      rulewaiver=RuleWaiverSerializer(read_only=True,many=True)

     class Meta:
         model= CheckModel
         fields = ('check_name','rulewaiver')

class RuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
         model=Rule
         fields=('id','rule_description')
class WaiverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
         model=Waiver
         fields=('id','desc')
class DeliverbalesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
         model=Deliverables
         fields=('id','name')
```

I want to serialize data in my following format

```
{
"p0_checks" : [
    {
        "check_id": "400",
        "rules" : [
            {
                "rule_id" : "21_22",
                "description": "checks blah blah",
                "deliverables" : ["del1"],
                 "waivers": [
                    {
                        "description" : "I will waive everything"
                    },
                    {
                         "description" : "I will waive all warnings"
                    }                   
                ]
            },
            {
                "rule_id" : "15217",
            "description": "checks blah blah"
                "req_ids" : ["lef"],
                "waivers": [
                    {
                        "description" : "I will waive everything"
                    },
                    {

                        "description" : "I will waive all warnings"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

Iam not sure how to get this json from serializers, Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class CheckModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      rulewaiver=RuleWaiverSerializer(read_only=True,many=True)

     class Meta:
         model= CheckModel
         fields = ('check_name','rulewaiver')
         depth=2
```

Your view

```
class CheckModelSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CheckModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CheckModelSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset
```

and access the url by adding the argument `?include=rulewaiver`

Comment: I have tried you solution, edited my url to this  url(r'^checksjson/?include=rulewaiver$', ChecksJSONView.get_queryset(),name='Check JSON') and Iam getting followintg error "unbound method get_queryset() must be called with ChecksJSONView instance as first argument (got nothing instead)"